# How do I take input from an asp web form to a visual basic back end?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

Here's what I've come up with so far (from other research):

```
Dim strStudentEmail As String = If(Request.Form("StudentEmail"), "")
```

However when I check the output from this it comes out blank.

The input comes from this text box markup on an asp webpage:

```
Student Email Address:
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="StudentEmail" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Email"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
```

P.S. I'm very new to asp & Visual Basic syntax.

Comment: If you are new... consider going with C# and ASP.NET MVC instead. [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the `Text` property? It's `String.Empty` even if you assign `Nothing`.

```
Dim strStudentEmail As String = StudentEmail.Text
```

Side-note: `Request.Form("StudentEmail")` is never `null/Nothing` but `String.Empty`, so no need for the `Null-Coalescing-Operator` at all.

`Request.Form` is populated only if the page is loaded through a form POST, so on postbacks and not on the inital load.